# Wordpress: Pass variable set from post editor to template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to set a variable value from my text editor that I can pass on the template code?

Comment: Please elaborate what you're trying to do and add the code you tried.

Comment: You just need to use Custom Fields on your page, then you can access them easily. More informations : https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: @VincentDecaux Can you please post this as an answer? This is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use Custom Fields on your page, then you can access them easily.

> More informations : https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

To access in your template :

```
 $custom = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $keyField);
```